# SAP BO Version upgrade problems with date format

Tags: business-objects

Post Upgrade, Client tools (Deski & Webi) are using US date format (MM/DD/YYYY). This is causing issues as users are earlier used to enter/view dates in UK date format (DD/MM/YYYY). We have updated regional settings on users machine to make sure it is UK format. Still in client tools it is not reflecting.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Interesting statement, maybe - but what is the programming-related question? This is not a BO suport forum.

Comment: Can this issue be resolved?